# SSRS Subscription adding a space around the 1000th character

Tags: html, sql, reporting-services

I have an SSRS subscription that runs off a stored procedure.

When the email is sent it is adding a space around the 1000th character of the email.

Unfortunately, there is a href in that space causing the link to fail.

The email has a few dynamic parts so the space comes up in different parts of the link. My users are very strict about formatting and want the link in that exact position.

Does anyone know of a way to stop the space from appearing? I have tried using a no-wrap tag but it still fails.

I apologize for the messy code. I havent posted to StackOverflow much.

```
 declare @Instructions nvarchar(max) = '<a style="white-space:nowrap;" href         ="http://www.uab.edu/research/administration/offices/OSP/Guidance/Pages/Instruct    ions-VAMOU.aspx">Instructions</a>'


'DATE: ' + CONVERT(varchar(10),@parmReportDate, 101) + '

To: ' + r.pi_name + '

From: nameaa aaaaaaaaaa

The UAB/VA Memorandum of Understanding (VA-MOU) defines the formal          arrangement between UAB and the Birmingham VAMC when a UAB investigator receives or applies for NIH funding, directly or by subaward through a UAB appointment, and that investigator also has a VA appointment.

Per the '+ @NIHPolicy+ ', the MOU must be updated with each significant change or at least one year from the last revision if there were no 
significant changes.  Significant changes include such things as a change in VA appointment or a change in research commitment of 25% or greater.'
+
'<b> This notification is a reminder that annual certification of your VA-MOU is due in ' +
CASE 
    WHEN @parmreportdate = DATEADD (Day, -60, p.app_end_dt) THEN '60' --and p.app_end_dt
    WHEN @parmreportdate = DATEADD (Day, -30, p.app_end_dt) THEN '30'
    WHEN @parmreportdate = DATEADD (Day, -15, p.app_end_dt) THEN '15'
    WHEN @parmreportdate = DATEADD (Day, 0, p.app_end_dt)   THEN '0'
END
+ ' days. Use the ' + @Instructions+ ' below to complete the annual certification '+ @VAMOUForm+ '. (This MOU is maintained in IRAP by OSP with an OSP Assigned Number of ' + r.inst_no + '.  You will need to reference this number when you complete the form.)

<b>Please direct any questions to the Office of Sponsored Programs at email or phonenumber.</b>'
```

Comment: This will be either (a) a data issue or (b) a coding issue but you will need to provide the source and the results in order to get some help.

Comment: Ill see what i can add in. it is happening in multiple subscriptions coded by different people. I wasnt sure if it was possibly an ssrs issue.

Comment: not sure why it added spaces on stackoverflow. here is no white space in my code in random places

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some hidden characters / white space in. Remove and all will be fine..

```
declare @Instructions nvarchar(max) = '<a style="white-space:nowrap;" href         ="http://www.uab.edu/research/administration/offices/OSP/Guidance/Pages/Instruct    ions-VAMOU.aspx">Instructions</a>'
```

becomes

```
declare @Instructions nvarchar(max) = '<a href ="http://www.uab.edu/research/administration/offices/OSP/Guidance/Pages/Instructions-VAMOU.aspx">Instructions</a>'
```

Comment: The white space above does not appear in my code in ssms. The issue is common among multiple reports in our ssrs. Always around the 1000th character. Is there a server configuration that can cause this?

Comment: No. Post a screenshot of the URL in your IDE please.

Comment: My reputation isnt high enought to post images